# Adding a datagrid inside a combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net

Anyone know how to do this. I just have a basic combo box and I have a datagrid that populates data from a database with multiple rows and columns. I want to have it when you click on the drop down the datagrid shows inside the the drop down. anyone know how to do this in vb.net , basic win form

Comment: create a popup window just below your 'Combobox', which itself would not open up. In that popup window, place your grid and react on ENTER, doubleclick etc. the popup window will disappear when you click outside of it. Sorry, I am not too familiar with Winforms, but that's how it basically would work.

Comment: Is this WPF/Silverlight/XAML or is this WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

on your form, place a DGV just below the cbo and set it to invisible.  in your cbo click:

```
    mcbo.Enabled = False
    mcbo.DroppedDown = False
    mdgv.Focus()
```

Turns off the cbo.   To restore:

```
Public Sub HideGrid()
    mdgv.Visible = False
    mcbo.Focus()
End Sub  

Private Sub mdgv_LostFocus(...
    HideGrid()
    mcbo.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Then somewhere on your grid depending on what data is there and how you are using it:

```
 mcbo.Text = Important_Text_From_Grid
```

It actually takes 300+ more lines of code to get it to look and act like a seemless pair and even then, it is only passable.